# How to save tensorflow dynamic_rnn model and restore them as an decoder in a new encoder-decoder model?

Tags: tensorflow, save, restore

I am trying to train a encoder-decoder model to automatically generate summary. the encoder part use CNN to encode article's abstract. the decoder part is RNN to generate article's title.

so the skeleton looks like:

```
encoder_state = CNNEncoder(encoder_inputs)
decoder_outputs, _ = RNNDecoder(encoder_state,decoder_inputs)
```

But I want to pre-trained the RNN decoder to teach the model to learn how to speak first. the decoder part is:

```
def RNNDecoder(encoder_state,decoder_inputs):
    decoder_inputs_embedded = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embeddings, decoder_inputs)
    #from tensorflow.models.rnn import rnn_cell, seq2seq
    cell = rnn.GRUCell(memory_dim)
    decoder_outputs, decoder_final_state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(
        cell, decoder_inputs_embedded,
        initial_state=encoder_state,
        dtype=tf.float32,scope="plain_decoder1"
    )
    return decoder_outputs, decoder_final_state
```

So my concern is how to save the save and restore RNNDecoder part separately?

Comment: do you want to train the RNNdecoder separately?

Comment: yes,I want it separately. Right now I just feed the CNN encoder with empty input to achieve this purpose, but I think this is less efficient.

Comment: But don't you need to feed a context vector from encoder to decoder ?

Comment: I am trying to pre-train this rnn decoder, with random context vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can take the output of the dynamic RNN first.

```
decoder_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell(decoder_hidden_units)
decoder_outputs, decoder_final_state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(decoder_cell, decoder_inputs_embedded,initial_state=encoder_final_state,dtype=tf.float32, time_major=True, scope="plain_decoder")
```

*Take the **decoder_outputs**. Then use a softmax layer to fully connect it.*

```
decoder_logits = tf.contrib.layers.linear(decoder_outputs, vocab_`size)
```

Then you can create a softmax loss with **decoder_logits** and train it in the noramal way.

**When you want to restore the parameters you this kind of method in a session**

```
with tf.Session() as session:
        saver = tf.train.Saver()
        saver.restore(session, checkpoint_file)
```

Here the checkpoint file should be your exact checkpoint file. So when running what happen is it will only restore your decoder weights and train with the main model.

Comment: Thanks @Shamane Siriwardhana , So this way I can restore them in a new  py script and pass it the real encoder output?

Comment: So you need to reload all the parameters only for the decoder right? Well that's kind of new thing for me. Any way you can reload model params with tf.train.saver.